# Microsoft Graph API using nextLink on calendarView results in ErrorAccessDenied

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

Doing a delta query on a calendarView I receive a nextLink even if there are no results.

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/..../calendars/..../calendarView/microsoft.graph.delta?startdatetime=2020-08-05T13:53:29.954Z&enddatetime=2021-08-05T13:53:30.151Z

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(event)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/..../calendars/..../calendarView/microsoft.graph.delta?$skiptoken=b9658zLYx7ag_WbFCK2mQj8933PsHHOxsDcYSWymakIJAcGkjxjTZWz4SsQI4Gu31DvwMi0kzqDrERlfvpdkmD73Q-qUZHD5hyPpuGzImOd5KAY6SFhuYJTLnvcBRo31v2UIm9miIbAHDoaY4ImhmxMa8bmAUKOL....",
    "value": []
}
```

Following that link to obtain a deltaLink results in a ErrorAccessDenied

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/..../calendars/..../calendarView/microsoft.graph.delta?$skiptoken=b9658zLYx7ag_WbFCK2mQj8933PsHHOxsDcYSWymakIJAcGkjxjTZWz4SsQI4Gu31DvwMi0kzqDrERlfvpdkmD73Q-qUZHD5hyPpuGzImOd5KAY6SFhuYJTLnvcBRo31v2UIm9miIbAHDoaY4ImhmxMa8bmAUKOL....

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-08-05T14:06:37",
      "request-id": "fa8341c3-3eb0-4465-825e-6d7e80f532cd"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing?
Is there a way to obtain the deltaToken on the first request if there is no object to return?

I've tried implementing this flow with msgraph-sdk-java 1.9.0 and with direct call using PostMan.

Comment: is it possible you don't have the access token when you're sending the nextlink request and/or the token is expired?

Comment: I've tried to generate a new token and use it in the call to the nextLink but nothing changes... 
I think is something in the mailbox configuration...

Answer (score 1):

I've tried again for hours but nothing worked.... until our client finally double checked his configuration and reassigned all the delegate permissions from scratch.

Now it works perfectly....